# FMOD How to Set a group of Events in some custom Channelgroup?

Tags: audio, fmod

FMOD How to Set a group of Events in some custom Channelgroup ?

I can create a custom channelgroup
But I don't know set a group of Events using it.
Event::Getchannelgroup seem not working.

Anyone know how to do that?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can normally create your sounds (sreaming or not it doesn't matter). You need to obtain pointer to a channel class and use Channel::setChannelGroup ()

....

```
FMOD::Sound        *Sound;  
FMOD::Channel      *Channel;  
FMOD::ChannelGroup *ChannelGroup;

System->createSound ("Sound.ogg", FMOD_DEFAULT, 0, &Sound);
System->playSound (FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, &Sound, true, &Channel);
Channel->setChannelGroup (ChannelGroup);
```

Also here is the link that can help you: http://katyscode.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/cutting-your-teeth-on-fmod-part-2-channel-groups/